# Not sure how to properly update persistent JPA entities

Tags: jpa

Let's say I have a Category entity that contains a list of Product entities which fall under that category:

```java
Category c = new Category(/*some JSON with category attributes*/);
```

The Category entity is persisted using this CategoryManager:

```java
// imports

@RequestScoped
public class CategoryManager {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public CategoryManager() {}

    @Transactional
    public void save(Category c) {
        em.persist(c);
    }

    public Category find(long id) {
        return em.find(Category.class, id);
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Now there's a function that is supposed to create a new Product entity and add it into the list of products of a certain category:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addProduct(ProductDTO product) {
    Category category = categoryManager.find(product.getCategory().getId());

    if (category == null)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Category not found.").build();

    Product new_product = new Product(product);
    productManager.save(new_product);
    category.getProducts().add(new_product);
    // categoryManager.save(category);

    return Response.ok(new_product).build();
}
```

This seems to update the database correctly, but when I try to list the category, its list of products appears empty in JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bread",
    "products": []
}
```

Only after I restart my Open Liberty server does it actually list the products correctly:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bread",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Wholegrain"
        }
    ]
}
```

I suspect it's because I don't save the category after appending the product to its list of products, but when I uncomment the commented out line in the code I posted, it complains about duplicate key values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up fixing this by adding the following to my CategoryManager:

```java
@Transactional
public Category update(Category c) {
    return em.merge(c);
}
```

And updating the addProduct() method like this:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addProduct(ProductDTO product) {
    Category category = categoryManager.find(product.getCategory().getId());

    if (category == null)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Category not found.").build();

    Product new_product = new Product(product);
    productManager.save(new_product);
    category.getProducts().add(new_product);
    categoryManager.update(category); // <---- the changed line

    return Response.ok(new_product).build();
}
```

It seems to have fixed the issue, but I'm open to suggestions and better solutions.

Comment: This is correct solution. Persist method of entity manager can only be used to save a new entity. Merge method is for update of existing one.

Comment: You'll want to have your addProduct method be transactional so that your find, save, and update calls are all in the same transaction. I don't know why the second transaction might fail, but you'll be left with an inserted Product no one knows about if it does, so why risk it - especially since you don't even really need that second transaction to touch the database by the looks of it.

Comment: Mar-Z: Thank you for your feedback once again! Chris: You're right, thanks. Is adding the @Transactional annotation enough, or is there something else I should do?